# A light alternative to gnome-system-monitor?

Tags: gnome, software-recommendation, system-monitor

As I'm programming a little game, I often use gnome-system-monitor to check if there's any memory leak in my program. But the monitor takes too much lime to launch and is pretty slow.

Could you suggest a graphical and light alternative to gnome-system-monitor ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can try

- [xfce4-taskmanager](https://linuxreviews.org/Xfce_Task_Manager) from Xfce or
- [lxtask](https://wiki.lxde.org/en/LXTask) from LXDE.

Neither of them pull any specific dependencies.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for (lxtask is great) !

Answer (score 26):

### **htop**

it is a terminal app:

```
sudo apt-get install htop
htop
```

[image: htop]
<sub>`htop` with graph mode</sub>

---

### **ProcMeter3**

Look for this system monitor (GUI works with GTK1,2,3):
[**ProcMeter3**](https://www.gedanken.org.uk/software/procmeter3/)

An utility which works with LCD devices even.

[image: ProcMeter3 GUI on GTK3]
<sub>ProcMeter3 GUI on GTK3</sub>

---

### **Psymon**

Also once I tried a **Psymon**. This is not extremely lightweight software and written
on **Qt** (not **GTK**, and therefore should work better with KDE) **though despite to this fact** it works well not only with Unity and Gnome, but also in other OS, like FreeBSD, MacOS, Windows etc., because it use great `python-psutil` Debian package.

So look it closer:

[Nice post about Psymon](http://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/01/free-system-monitor-ubuntu-linux-windows-psymon/)

[Psymon project site](http://code.google.com/p/psymon/)

[image: Psymon]
<sub>Psymon</sub>

Answer (score 8):

**ndicator-SysMonitor**
Indicator-SysMonitor does a little, but does it well. Once installed and run, it displays CPU and RAM usage on your top panel. Simple.

[image]

Download from [here](https://launchpad.net/~alexeftimie/+archive/ppa/+packages)

**Conky**

One of my personal favourites

[image]

**Screenlet**
you’ll find a bunch of differently styled CPU and RAM monitors included in the screenlets-all package available in the Ubuntu Software Center.

[image]

**Glances**

To install:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip build-essential python-dev
sudo pip install Glances
sudo pip install PySensors
```

[image]

**VMSTAT**

Displays information about CPU, memory, processes, etc.

**IOSTAT**

This command line tool will display statistics about your CPU, I/O information for your hard disk partitions, Network File System (NFS), etc. To install iostat, run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install sysstat
```

To start the report, run this command:

```
iostat
```

To check only CPU statistics, use this command:

```
iostat -c
```

For more parameters, use this command:

```
iostat --help
```

**MPSTAT**

The mpstat command line utility will display average CPU usage per processor. To run it, use simply this command:

```
mpstat
```

For CPU usage per processor, use this command:

```
mpstat -P ALL
```

**Saidar**

Saidar also allows to monitor system device activities via the command line.

[image]

You can install is with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install saidar
```

To start monitoring, run this command:

```
saidar -c -d 1
```

Stats will be refreshed every second.

**GKrellM**

GKrellM is a customizable widget with various themes that displays on your desktop system device information (CPU, temperature, memory, network, etc.).

[image]

To install GKrellM, run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install gkrellm
```

**Monitorix**

Monitorix is another application with a web-based user interface for monitoring system devices.

[image]

Install it with these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:upubuntu-com/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install monitorix
```

Start Monitorix via this URL:

```
http://localhost/monitorix/
```

Comment: Best answer in this thread, all the information you would need

Answer (score 7):

One tool is **gkrellm** .

It is very configurable and expandable, and has numerous plugins, skins, etc..

[image: configuration and main display]

```
$ apt-cache search gkrellm
gkrellkam - GKrellM plugin that displays a periodically updating image
gkrellm - GNU Krell Monitors
gkrellm-bfm - system load plugin for gkrellm with a duck
gkrellm-gkrellmpc - GKrellM plugin for controlling MPD
gkrellm-hdplop - hard drive activity monitor GKrellM plugin
gkrellm-ibam - Advanced battery monitor for laptops - gkrellm plugin
gkrellm-leds - Keyboard LED monitor for GKrellM
gkrellm-mailwatch - GKrellM plugin to watch mailboxes in multiple panels
gkrellm-mldonkey - mldonkey plugin for gkrellm2
gkrellm-radio - FM radio tuner for GKrellM
gkrellm-reminder - useful reminder plugin for gkrellm
gkrellm-snmp - snmp plug-in for GKrellM
gkrellm-thinkbat - ThinkPad laptops battery status indicator for GKrellM
gkrellm-volume - A mixer plugin for GKrellM
gkrellm-x86info - gkrellm plugin displaying the current processor speed
gkrellm-xkb - Keyboard layout indicator plugin for GKrellM
gkrellmapcupsd - gkrellm plugin displaying the current processor speed
gkrellmd - GNU Krell Monitors Server
gkrellmitime - Internet time plugin for gkrellm
gkrellmoon - Gkrellm Moon Clock Plugin
gkrellmwireless - 802.11 wireless link monitor plugin for GKrellM
gkrellshoot - Plugin for gkrellm to lock the screen and make screenshots
gkrelltop - Top three intensive processes plugin for gkrellm
gkrelltopd - Top three intensive processes plugin for gkrellmd
gkrelluim - GKrellM plugin for uim
gkrellweather - A weather monitor plugin for GKrellM
gkrellxmms2 - GKrellM plugin to control xmms2
```

Answer (score 6):

I use the System Load Indicator to monitor CPU & memory use, if i notice anything unusual then I can go to gnome-system-monitor or top to find the culprit.

[System Load Indicator PPA](https://launchpad.net/indicator-multiload)

[image: Load Indicator showing CPU use only]

Sample image showing current CPU use only.

Answer (score 5):

I know you said "graphical", but try running `top` in a terminal. It's extremely lightweight and gives plenty of information.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.
I tried ``top`` before and it's quite useful, but I'd still prefer a graphical alternative !

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking a look at a program called `qps`. It's a old Qt application that does the job very well. You should be able to find a patch for it that adds support for affinity control. it is ULTRA-lightweight (< 1MB executable, statically linked to QT 1.41 !). You can install qps from the Ubuntu Software Center.