# what are the system monitor applications avaliable?

Tags: command-line, system-monitor

May I know what are the system monitor applications available in Ubuntu (GUI/CLI)?

Comment: posted to help others. even its a basic one. may be some of us missing some awesome tools. down there I am posting what I know. Please improve it if you know anything new.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A light alternative to gnome-system-monitor?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/124159/a-light-alternative-to-gnome-system-monitor)

Comment: I don't think this is too broad, basically because a limited number of answers is possible (and in fact there is a very good answer). I am voting to reopen, but let's see where democracy takes us.

Comment: Okay I will wait. If no changes , I can think it is the time. @don.joey thanks for your support.

Answer (score 6):

**ndicator-SysMonitor**
Indicator-SysMonitor does a little, but does it well. Once installed and run, it displays CPU and RAM usage on your top panel. Simple.

[image]

Download from [here](https://launchpad.net/~alexeftimie/+archive/ppa/+packages)

**Conky**

One of my personal favourites

[image]

**Screenlet**
you’ll find a bunch of differently styled CPU and RAM monitors included in the screenlets-all package available in the Ubuntu Software Center.

[image]

**Glances**

To install:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip build-essential python-dev
sudo pip install Glances
sudo pip install PySensors
```

[image]

**VMSTAT**

Displays information about CPU, memory, processes, etc.

**IOSTAT**

This command line tool will display statistics about your CPU, I/O information for your hard disk partitions, Network File System (NFS), etc. To install iostat, run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install sysstat
```

To start the report, run this command:

```
iostat
```

To check only CPU statistics, use this command:

```
iostat -c
```

For more parameters, use this command:

```
iostat --help
```

**MPSTAT**

The mpstat command line utility will display average CPU usage per processor. To run it, use simply this command:

```
mpstat
```

For CPU usage per processor, use this command:

```
mpstat -P ALL
```

**Saidar**

Saidar also allows to monitor system device activities via the command line.

[image]

You can install is with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install saidar
```

To start monitoring, run this command:

```
saidar -c -d 1
```

Stats will be refreshed every second.

**GKrellM**

GKrellM is a customizable widget with various themes that displays on your desktop system device information (CPU, temperature, memory, network, etc.).

[image]

To install GKrellM, run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install gkrellm
```

**Monitorix**

Monitorix is another application with a web-based user interface for monitoring system devices.

[image]

Install it with these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:upubuntu-com/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install monitorix
```

Start Monitorix via this URL:

```
http://localhost/monitorix/
```

Answer (score 3):

You also have **iotop** to monitor I/O

Run it as,

```
sudo iotop
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK

1. Gnome System monitor

This is default in every Ubuntu installation. Just type as monitor in Unity dash and it will list you.

[image]

2 . top

This is a CLI tool , Open your terminal and and type top and you can view it.

[image]
3 . htop

This is not default one . you have to install it by using

```
sudo apt-get install htop
```

[image]

4 . nmon

This is also not default one. You have to install it manually with

```
sudo apt-get install nmon
```

[image]

hope that helps.

Comment: Writing "hope that helps" on your own question is just wrong.

Comment: @Alvar read my comment please. Help to others