# Tool like GeekTool [ see logs on your desktop ]

Tags: log, monitoring

Anyone know of a good alternative to [geektool](http://projects.tynsoe.org/en/geektool/) in macos x?  I recently switched to ubuntu and it's not compatible with ubuntu.

Geektool lets you display various information on your desktop, like log files, system ressource usage or the output of any shellscript.

Answer (score 2):

Search for `log` in dash. Look for:
[image: Look for 'System Log', 'Log Viewer' etc]

You can go through various logs:
[image]

You can also use it to open and view other logs.

To view the log currently in memory, run `dmesg`, you may want to maximise the terminal first, as there is quite alot of output...

For current System Usage, use 'System Monitor':
[image]

And for the rest, just use Terminal

Comment: Thanks for your reply but all are missing one important feature is that showing the log in desktop.

Comment: See this [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/124159/178596) and [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/321018/setting-up-conky-on-ubuntu).

Comment: thanks but with conky it not that straight forward.

Comment: It should be fairly straightforward - did you try [these instructions](http://askubuntu.com/a/344463/178596)?

Comment: I did but I have to issues.
 1) I am using kbuntu and not gnome.
 2) I dont want all the stuff around it.  Just want the log monitor.

Answer (score 0):

If you install KDE Plasma as a display environment, you can install the Termoid widget (requires the package `qmltermwidget`).

This makes it possible to run arbitrary commands and have the standard output displayed directly on your desktop. It can be rerun at given intervals (making it dynamic) as on Geektools.